# Speeding up slow vmware win 7 with ubuntu 14 as host?

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware

I set 4 GB RAM for the Guest win 7, a disk of 30 GB.

My ubuntu scpecs are: 16 GB RAM, i7 4510 4 cores @2.00 GHz.

It runs smoothly when using the desktop environment, but when I start using OFFICE and I try to type is almost impossible. Is there a way to give more cores to the virtual machine? The options on the vmware 12 are disabled, I can see the menu tool-tip, but it do not allows me to edit it.

Comment: Have you tried installing VMware tools on the guest?

Comment: @Ken Yes, but I think is a problem of the graphics controller or something like it...